# Using $resource factory not able to post plain text data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax

Not able to post plain text using $resource factory but It's work via postman client. Below the postman CURL details -

```
curl -X POST \
https://23.48.46.30/guacamole/api/tokens \
-H 'authorization: Basic bmViQWRtaW5AbmViOmJjZGIwYjExZmY4NmVmMDI=' \
-H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
-H 'postman-token: 82425dc4-d4ef-306c-8087-cd7c4890903e' \
-d token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJ1MSIsInJvbCI6ImFkbWluIiwiYXVkIjoibmViY2xpZW5kaWQxIiwiaXNzIjoiTmViIiwiZ3VhYy5wb3J0IjoiMTY0MDYiLCJndWFjLnByb3RvY29sIjoiVk5DIiwidGVuYW50IjoidDEiLCJleHAiOjE1NDM2NjA1MjUsImd1YWMuaG9zdG5hbWUiOiJsb2NhbGhvc3QiLCJpYXQiOjE1NDM2NTg3MjUsInJscyI6WyJhZG1pbiJdLCJHVUFDX0lEIjoiZDBiNDhmNTItYjI3My00ZWZhLTg0ZTQtODdmNTJlMTVlN2FiIn0.7D6Cuz-jAaT9wP9U68M5UridxnReYbN_7qw_QPYnhEo
```

Pls, see the attached screenshot, how I'm passing the data in browser payload but BE sending 500 Internal Server Error while It's perfectly working in postman client. Any idea pls do share ...

[image]

Comment: In general $resource factories don't work with primitives such as strings. They only work with objects or arrays.

Comment: Is it possible using angular $http service??